# Pytorch: executiin on GPU: RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #3 'index'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

How to make model execute on GPU in Pytorch?

I load model like:

```
def load_tocotron_2_model():
    model = Tacotron2(num_chars=n_chars, r=CONFIG.r, attn_win=CONFIG.windowing, attn_norm=CONFIG.attention_norm,
                      prenet_type=CONFIG.prenet_type, forward_attn=CONFIG.use_forward_attn,
                      trans_agent=CONFIG.transition_agent)

    if use_cuda:
        cp = torch.load(MODEL_PATH)
    else:
        cp = torch.load(MODEL_PATH, map_location='cpu')

    model.load_state_dict(cp['model'])

    if use_cuda:
        model.cuda()

    model.eval() # Set eval mode

    return model
```

If `use_cuda` is False then model runs ok, but if it's True I get error:

```
  File "/data/user/external_projects/text-to-speech/mozila-tts-wavernn-cpu/TTS/models/tacotron2.py", line 50, in inference
    embedded_inputs = self.embedding(text).transpose(1, 2)
  File "/data/user/external_projects/text-to-speech/mozila-tts-wavernn-cpu/TTS/my_env_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/data/user/external_projects/text-to-speech/mozila-tts-wavernn-cpu/TTS/my_env_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py", line 117, in forward
    self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)
  File "/data/user/external_projects/text-to-speech/mozila-tts-wavernn-cpu/TTS/my_env_gpu/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1506, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CUDA but got backend CPU for argument #3 'index'
```

`self.embedding` is `self.embedding = nn.Embedding(num_chars, 512)`, do I need to specify `.cuda()` on some tensor or `model.cuda()` is sufficient?